# Mapped method to get all items returns an empty list

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am learning Spring Boot via [this Lynda tutorial](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/learning-spring-with-spring-boot).

Through the GET method `/room` I should be able to get a list of all the current rooms in my embedded database. Both the `schema.sql` and `data.sql` files are in place.

**My entity class `Room.java`:**

```
package com.frankmoley.landon.data.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ROOM")
public class Room {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ROOM_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "ROOM_NUMBER")
    private String number;
    @Column(name = "BED_INFO")
    private String bedInfo;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getBedInfo() {
        return bedInfo;
    }

    public void setBedInfo(String bedInfo) {
        this.bedInfo = bedInfo;
    }

}
```

**The repository class `RoomRepository.java`:**

```
package com.frankmoley.landon.data.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.frankmoley.landon.data.entity.Room;

@Repository
public interface RoomRepository extends CrudRepository<Room, Long> {

    Room findByNumber(String number);
}
```

And this is a temporary controller class we create just to test this one method (`RoomController.java`):

```
package com.frankmoley.landon.data.webservice;

import com.frankmoley.landon.data.entity.Room;
import com.frankmoley.landon.data.repository.RoomRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class RoomController {
    @Autowired
    private RoomRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value="/rooms", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    List<Room> findAll(@RequestParam(required=false) String roomNumber){
       List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<>();
        if(null==roomNumber){
            Iterable<Room> results = this.repository.findAll();
            results.forEach(room-> {rooms.add(room);});
        }else{
            Room room = this.repository.findByNumber(roomNumber);
            if(null!=room) {
                rooms.add(room);
            }
        }
        return rooms;
    }
}
```

When I run the application, I see the message regarding this mapping in Eclipse:

> Mapped "{[/rooms],methods=[GET]}" onto
>   java.util.List
>   com.frankmoley.landon.data.webservice.RoomController.findAll(java.lang.String)

But when I navigate to `localhost:8080/rooms`, all I get is an empty JSON object.

**application.properties:**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.dll-auto=none
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set update on ddl-auto, anything else then **create** or **create-drop**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Comment: The update change seems to solve the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Please, if possible, modify your answer so it's right to the point.

Comment: done. this was my first correct answer on stackoverflow )

Comment: Congratulations! Keep going.